# What Data Structure can i use here?

Tags: c#, linq

I have a a line of code that looks like this

```
var results = DataBase.Find(x.ImportanceFactor > 5 && x.ImportanceFactor < 10);
```

Now in the `Find`function, what Data Structure can i use?

```
public static int Find(??? input)
{
:
Some Code
:
}
```

The format needs to be exactly how i specified above, but i have having a hard time finding a data structure to support it. I have tried a number of Expressions in `Linq` to no success.

EDIT For Clarification:

The `Find` function will go into the a database and look for an object whose importance is within the specified range, and return whichever object in that range has the highest Size value. Again, that first line cant be changed in any way, regardless of what happens in the Find function. The line below needs to be available in the `Find`

```
x.ImportanceFactor > 5 && x.ImportanceFactor < 10
```

EDIT2:

X is a dynamic expression, not an object with properties.

Comment: Have you heard of `Where` extension method of the `System.Linq` namespace?

Comment: `Func<T, bool>`?  Though based on the usage example, it looks like it would just be a `bool`.

Comment: Nope, and from a quick glance, the syntax seams to be different.

Comment: Use `Predicate<T>` (same signature as `Func<T, bool>`, but the semantics are more appropriate). And change `x.etc` to `x => x.etc`

Comment: what is the `int` that is returned?

Comment: just use where, why reinvent  the wheel

Comment: @Coder1409 `Where` returns a `IEnumerable`, OP wants an `int`

Comment: @thumbmunkeys how can he has an int if there are more than one result , if he want to have one result just use FirstOrDefault with the desired predicate

Comment: the int is some arbitrary value that will be returned, and the syntax the parameters are specified cant be changed in any way.

Comment: @Coder1409: Semantically it's really unclear what this `Find()` method is even supposed to do.  Though I suspect its internal implementation is going to make use of something like `Where`, or `Any`, or `Count`.

Comment: @Coder1409 could be an aggregation function too, it's unclear what is asked anyway

Comment: @user2824991 and what are you gonna do with the matching data? what the point of returning a random int ?

Answer (score 1):

This:

```
x.ImportanceFactor > 5 && x.ImportanceFactor < 10
```

is just a `bool`:

```
public static int Find(bool input)
```

But given the usage of `x` in that condition, I *suspect* you actually meant this:

```
var results = DataBase.Find(x => x.ImportanceFactor > 5 && x.ImportanceFactor < 10);
```

In which case you're looking at something structurally very similar to methods like `Any()` or `Where()` [on `IEnumerable<T>`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ckzcawb8(v=vs.110).aspx).  That would use something more like `Func<T, bool>`:

```
public static int Find<T>(Func<T, bool> input)
```

Comment: I addicted the original question. I didnt specify that x is a dynamic expression, and not an object with parameters. I basically want
{x.ImportanceFactor > 5 && x.ImportanceFactor < 10} to be available in the Find method

Comment: @user2824991: That's what a `Func<>` is.  It's an expression which can be executed within the `Find()` method.

Comment: .Find<T>(System.Func<T,bool>)' cannot be inferred from the usage. Try specifying the type arguments explicitly.

That is the error i get

Comment: @user2824991: How are you using it?  If you need to specify the type for `x` then just specify it as the type argument to the method.  This would work just like any other LINQ methods on `IEnumerable<T>`.

Comment: In the example x is of type T, I am not sure but OP may want input to be

Func<IEnumerable<T>, bool>, which is to figure out condition using Enumerable.Any